# Undefined data returned from JSON in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a simple web application that has a `HouseUnitController` with an action that returns a `JSONResult`.

```
public JsonResult GetHouseUnits()
    {
        var houseUnits = db.HouseUnits.Include(h => h.HouseModel).Include(h => h.Site)
           .Select(h => new {
                    h.Block,
                    h.Lot,
                    h.HouseModel.ModelName,
                    h.Site.SiteName,
                    h.IsSold,
                    h.FloorArea,
                    h.LotArea,
                    h.Price
        });
        return Json(houseUnits, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my view, I have:

```
<button data-retrieve data-view="tree" data-service = "./GetHouseUnits" data-container="#view" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>Load Data </strong>&nbsp;</button>
```

When I browse `localhost:62516/HouseUnits/GetHouseUnits`, I can see the JSON result that was returned. However, when I click the button, I do not receive any data. Here is my script file which is working for other html pages:

```
$('button[data-retrieve]').click(function(){
    var treeHeaderLimit = 2;    
    var APIurl = $(this).data('service');
    var view = $(this).data("view");
    var dataCount = 5;
    var selId = $(this).data("container");

    createView(APIurl, selId, view, dataCount, treeHeaderLimit);

});
```

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the url in the button, because it seems that the data that was returned from AJAX was `undefined`.

```
function createView(APIurl, selId, viewType, dataCount, treeHeaderLimit){
 $.ajax({
    url: APIurl,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json", //This is used to avoid `No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header error
    success:function(data){

        if (viewType=="tree"){
            generateTree(data, selId, dataCount, treeHeaderLimit)
        } else{
            generateTable(data, selId, dataCount);
        }

    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});

}
```

Can someone please help me with this problem? I've tried `./GetHouseUnits` and `../GetHouseUnits` but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: try to use Url.Action() instead of static URL's

Comment: did you try `HouseUnits/GetHouseUnits` for the data-service attribute?

Comment: Thanks @FrebinFrancis . Post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your static URL's with the Url.Action() method in ASP.NET MVC

instead of `data-service = "./GetHouseUnits"` use `"@Url.Action("{action}","{controller}")"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The url should be in the format of `../Controller-Name/Action-Name.`
Change the `data-service="./GetHouseUnits"` to `data-service="../Controller-Name/Action-Name"`.
To make sure that you are using the correct url, just you have to place a break point in the action.
If you are using correct url, then the respective action will shown for iteration and if not using the action, then the url is wrong.